# Resize columns in word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found 4 related methods:

```
.width

.setwidth

.preferredwidth

.columnwidth
```

Could anyone help me to understand the differences among them? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Tried? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.column

Comment: ColumnWidth is nothing to do with tables. The other 3 are explained in the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.column, which you can access directly from the Object Browser by right clicking and selecting Help.

Comment: I tried to use something like columns(12).width=InchesToPoints(0.69), but the column 12 stays at 0.79. Not sure what should be done. I turned off autofit already...